# Почему исчезают скобки в регулярном выражении?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Я добавил скобки() в регулярное выражение, чтобы они не исчезали в тексте. Если я уберу правую часть после | где r,n,f, то скобки остаются, в данном ниже варианте скобки исчезают. В чем может быть проблема? Нужно чтобы правая часть осталась, иначе не работает перенос на новую строчку

```
const document = /([^0-9a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ\s.,№"'-()]|[(\r\n|\r|\f|\n|\u200B)])/gm;

const allowedText = issuer.replace(document, ' ');
```

Comment: А вы проверили бы свою регулярку на https://regex101.com/ (только `\u200B` он не понимает, но можно остальное разобрать) мне кажется вы что-то намудрили в правой части, `|` (т.е. "или") внутри квадратных скобок не работает, их наверное справа вообще нужно убрать. Сейчас у вас всё что справа внутри квадратных скобок воспринимается как отдельные символы, получается вы слева круглые скобки исключили, а справа наоборот включили. А в остальном без примеров непонятно что вы хотели вообще.

Comment: @CrazyElf это php не понимает, Net, Java 8, Python, Js - понимают \u200B

Comment: @splash58 А, точно, там же язык можно переключать, редко пользуюсь, забыл

Comment: Приведите пример текста изначального и что должно получиться, но не получается

Comment: Посмотрите на ваш `[(\r\n|\r|\f|\n|\u200B)]`, видите скобки? Удалите их - вот и решение. `/([^0-9a-zа-яё\s.,№"'()-]|[\r\n\f\u200B])/gi`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew спасибо большое) все корректно отрабатывает)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```js
/[^0-9a-zа-яё\s.,№"'()-]|[\r\n\f\u200B]/gi
```

Флаг `i` отвечает за регистронезависимый поиск.

- `[^0-9a-zа-яё\s.,№"'()-]` - один из символов, отличный от тех, которые заданы в отрицающем символьном класее
- `|` - или
- `[\r\n\f\u200B]` - знак перевода каретки, перевода на новую строку, Form feed и пробел нулевой длины.